# different date in datebox when using IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-easyui

I'm using a jQuery Easyui datebox and use the value as queryparam in an url.

```
var date = $('#dd').datebox('getValue');
window.open('file.php?date='.date);
```

I leave the datebox empty and fire the code.
When I check file.php in IE 8.0 I get `$_GET['date']='1970-01-01'` 
but in Chrome v32.0 it is `$_GET['date']='0';`

Can anyone explain why and give a hint so I can send the same value with the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add this to make sure to send the same value:

```
var date = $('#dd').datebox('getValue');
if(date == 0 || date == '0' || date == '1970-01-01' || !date)
date = 0; //or '1970-01-01' if you prefer that one.
window.open('file.php?date='.date);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution,
Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: you could accept/upvote this answer if it helped you.

Comment: i guess the datebox is using different algorithms in different browsers and thus in IE 8 it first convertss `""` to 0 and then formats it as if 0 is a unix_timestamp.

Comment: $('#dd').databox('getValue') returns a string instead of a date/time. So Chrome converts it into a number, IE threaths it as a dateformat.
Maybe causing the difference.